# Jquery datepicker format and database date type

Tags: jquery, user-interface

I am trying to change Jquery UI datepicker format to euro time. I added this line

```
 $( "#datepicker,#vreme2" ).datepicker();
     $( "#datepicker,#vreme2" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
```

but in database i got wrong format for example 2050-20-10

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Describe what do you want to achieve in js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your datepicker format to below

```
$( "#datepicker,#vreme2" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy.mm.dd");
```

as database by default accpets date int YYYY-MM-DD format.